# Simulate Push Notification (IOS5) without apn

Tags: objective-c, ios5, notifications, push

I want to simulate push notification without using apn.
I have tried to HOOK SBSystemLocalNotificationAlert 
and use

```
[objc_getClass("SBSystemLocalNotificationAlert") presentWithLocalNotification:notification application:bundle];
```

but it is just an alertview not like ios5 notification center, and it looks like ios4's push.

I want to simulate push notification (IOS5) for my daemon like MobileSMS.

sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate push notifications without APN service, you can try this library: https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications

Works in the simulator too.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough issue. I do not know whether it is possible (correct me guys if I am wrong).

However if you only need this for testing, you can use Parse.com for sending push notifications. Their basic service that includes push notification is for free and they deliver a working example code how to integrate.

Comment: it's daemon,i can't use apn,SO i want HOOK the notification to simulate push notification.